# Pin a build from another build

Tags: teamcity, build-automation

I am using TeamCity 9.1.3. I have a main build which have artifacts dependency on 4 other builds. When the main build is run it picks artifacts of the last successful build from the 4 other builds and deploy it on to a test machine. The main build is only run when we want to deploy on test machine.

What I want to achieve is to pin the 4 builds that are being used by the main build for deployment when I run the main build. I am not able to find a way to do this.

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

I think these links might help:

- [Programatically pin a build in Teamcity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545710/programatically-pin-a-build-in-teamcity)
- A [TeamCity plugin available on Github](https://github.com/carlspring/teamcity-buildTagsViaBuildLog-plugin).

I had a similar issue and ended up writing a simple plugin similar to the one available on Github. I think you can just use the REST API for this.